# ERROR running force:project:create: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

I am trying to follow a Trailhead which instructs me to create a SFDX project in VS Code.  I've been using VS Code for awhile and all is current. While troubleshooting this issue, I did update my Salesforce CLI extension, but it was already current.

I'm at a loss.  Please help!

Comment: Please edit your question to give more detail: What's the name/link of the Trailhead module? What is the exact VS Code command you are running from the command palette? Both of the project commands (`Create Project` and `Create Project with Manifest`) will prompt you for a project name and then open a window to indicate where the project files should go. Are you seeing those prompts and entering/selecting valid options?

Answer (score 1):

You may also need to check and re-install the latest version of VS Code even if "Check for updates" says you're on the current version

Comment: Please mark this as the correct answer if it answered your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I remember facing this issue a while back. There can be two fixes I can think of

1. Run

   > sfdx update

   and update your VSCode extensions. If this fixes your issue it's likely because of SFDX CLI has now moved to OCLIF framework rendering some backward compatibility issues.
2. Create a blank package.json file in the directory where you're running the project:create command.